# How to make a respond_to by AJAX in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ajax, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1, respond-to

I have a form, that I send with using AJAX. The form is in the `FirstsController`. I need the form send to `SecondsController`. The form is sent and data saved. Then I wanna change the form by a text, I try to do by this way:

```
  def create
   ...saving...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { 
        render :update do |page|; page << "$('#id_element').html('hellllloooooo');" end  
       }
      format.html {} 
    end
  end
```

And I ma getting this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template seconds/update, application/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.):
```

How should I set the JS request back to the `FirstsController`? + is needed any help *.js file?

Comment: That error is saying that you are calling the update method and there's no template file for it. But in your example code you are using the create method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right set up to do it:

```
 def create
   ...saving...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { 
        render 'firsts/action_that_you_want' 
       }
      format.html {} 
    end
  end
```

And in the `FirstsController` is needed to have created the the file `action_that_you_want.js.erb`.