# why would request.format be text/javascript while respond_to format says it's not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.1.1

I'm setting up a dialog that is supposed to post back to the server via ajax, then show a 'done' message when it's completed.

```
  <%= form_tag '/tracking/add',  :remote => true, :id => 'add_tracking_request', 
      :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'} do %>
  ....
```

Ok so that's getting back to the server, doing all of its work etc. and then getting to respond_to:

```
   135          puts 'returning ...'
   136          if current_user
   137            respond_to do |format|
   138              debugger
=> 139              format.html { redirect_to :myTrackingRequests and return }
   140              format.js { head :ok, :success => 'true' }
   141            end
   142          else
   143            raise 'no user found at the end of create tracking'
(rdb:67) e format
#<ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector:0x007f98d63417c0 @default_response=#<Proc:0x007f98d6341720@/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:268>, @responses={}, @order=[]>
(rdb:67) e format.html
nil
(rdb:67) e format.js
nil
(rdb:67) e format.json
nil
(rdb:67) request.format
text/javascript
(rdb:67) request.post? 
true
(rdb:67)
```

I'm in a position where the object passed to respond_to block says it is not html, js or json, but the request is a post and its format is text/javascript. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag '/tracking/add',  :remote => true, :id => 'add_tracking_request', 'data-type' => 'json' do %>
```

Comment: Thought I had that covered in the :html hash. No?

Comment: no, look at the html source, :html => {} puts attribute html="..."

Comment: Crap, you're right. I lifted that code off of someone's Rails blog post ... wonder how it was so wrong.

Comment: Ok fixing that didn't fix the issue with respond_to; format.json is still nil as is format.js.

Comment: read the next answer. Check it out: put <%= request.xhr? %> into the template and see it returns true

Comment: I think I'm using that respond_to correctly, I've seen it in many places: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042155/how-to-make-a-respond-to-by-ajax-in-rails-3. Request.xhr? returned 0. Odd.

Comment: request.xhr? #=> 0 - is 'true' :) I don't see anything weird there. But what request.formats returns?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21548/discussion-between-jcollum-and-valery-kvon)

Answer (score 0):

The `format` object you get in the respond_to block is just simple container (Collector) that collects responses. It returns `nil` for every type because the script haven't reached the point where they are actually defined.

See the implementation here [ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L397).

Comment: I've seen this respond_to at the end of many many controller actions. So it looks right to me. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, look at the implementation. There's nothing wrong with using it, it's just a container, it doesn't do anything else. You can invoke it yourself, format.text { "Yay!" } and then format.text.call